# Error when trying to change the RGBQUAD of a 24 bit bitmap

Tags: mfc, bitmap

I have an application made in MFC using Visual Studio 6.0 where i am changing the color depth of the bitmap, the application works fine for all the bitmap except for 24 bit bitmap images. I am unable the figure out why it gives error. I know the place where it gives error.
Here's the code.

```
void CbitmapView::OnMenuRedMode() 
{
CBmpViewerDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
if(pDoc->m_bColorModeFlag == TRUE){

#ifdef _DEBUG
    CMemoryState oldState,newState,diffState;
    oldState.Checkpoint();
#endif
m_bmiView = (BITMAPINFO *)malloc(pDoc->dwInfoSize);
//m_bmiView = (BITMAPINFO *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR,pDoc->dwInfoSize);
CopyMemory(m_bmiView,pDoc->m_bitmapinfo,pDoc->dwInfoSize);
//  m_bmiView = pDoc->m_bitmapinfo;
int nColorUsed = m_bmiView->bmiHeader.biClrUsed ;
if(nColorUsed != 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < nColorUsed ; i++){
        m_bmiView->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)255;
    }
}else if(nColorUsed == 0){
    nColorUsed = (1 << pDoc->m_bitmapinfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed);
    for(int i = 0; i < nColorUsed ; i++){

        m_bmiView->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)255;
    }
}

pDoc->m_bmpHandle = CreateDIBSection(NULL, m_bmiView,DIB_RGB_COLORS,
    (void **)&pBitsView, NULL, 0);

CopyMemory(pBitsView,pDoc->m_pBits,pDoc->dwBitsSize);
if(m_bmiView != NULL){
    //GlobalFree(m_bmiView);
    free(m_bmiView);   *//error comes at this point when it is 24 bitmap image.*
    //delete(m_bmiView);
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
newState.Checkpoint();
if(diffState.Difference(oldState,newState)){
    MessageBox(_T("Memory leak detected"));
    diffState.DumpAllObjectsSince();
}
#endif

Invalidate();
// TODO: Add your command handler code here
}
```

}

The erorr is as follows shown by VS6.0

DAMAGE: after Normal block (#234) at 0x00423DF0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24bit Bitmaps don't have a bmiColor entry!
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx

> Blockquote
>   The bitmap has a maximum of 2^24 colors, and the bmiColors member of BITMAPINFO is NULL. Each 3-byte triplet in the bitmap array represents the relative intensities of blue, green, and red, respectively, for a pixel. The bmiColors color table is used for optimizing colors used on palette-based devices, and must contain the number of entries specified by the biClrUsed member of the BITMAPINFOHEADER

Comment: In that case than how to change the color of the 24 bit bitmap color ? Could you please point me to tutorial or give me some hint which can be used to change the color of 24 bit bitmap.

Comment: You Need to change every Pixel... there is no Color index.

Comment: Ok I have the pixel data with me. So I have to traverse through all the pixels and set the color depth of what ever color i want.
Could this two function GetPixel() & SetPixel() be useful in this case ? Can you please give me any tutorial for reference.

Comment: For sure it is faster to modify the data directly in the Bitmap instead of using GetPixel/SetPixel in a DC.
What do you want to do? Setting the red part of the RGB value to 100%? What is the sense behind that?

Comment: Basically what i want to do is boost the red color and keep rest of the color untouched, In that way i will get image looking as if its with red color filter (eg. Sepia kind of image)I want same kind of image in R,G,B. Thats what i want to do.

Comment: Than I would recommend getting bytes of the bitmap into the memory. Walk over each pixel and change the R channel to 255. Like you have done it before in the colors array of the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

GetPixel and SetPixel are incredibly slow: It could take minutes to change all the pixels with them. It will be much faster to map the pixel data into memory so you can directly address and modify it. To do this use CreateDIBSection. There is a good example of using this function at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31/A-DIBSection-wrapper-for-Win32-and-WinCE